# Parse - Empty Table Checking

Tags: android, parse-platform

How to check if table is empty using parse , I'm having a problem with the code below :

```
private String[] getMaxDateMessage() throws ParseException {
    final String[] msgData = new String[3];
    ParseObject ob = null;
    String[] userIds = {currentUserId, recipientId};
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ParseMessage");

    query.whereContainedIn("senderId", Arrays.asList(userIds));
    query.whereContainedIn("recipientId", Arrays.asList(userIds));
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

    if(query.hasCachedResult())
    {
    ob = query.getFirst();

        if (ob.isDataAvailable()) {
            //for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            //createdDate[0] = messageList.get(i).get("createdAt").toString();
            msgData[0] = ob.getCreatedAt().toString();
            msgData[1] = ob.get("senderId").toString();
            msgData[2] = ob.get("recipientId").toString();
            // }
        }
    }
```

The thing is that the table is empty , so the query should return null , but no exception is been throwed , it just crashes the app .
So how can I check if the table is empty before trying to fetch any data ?

Update : The solution that I have found is to use query.count().
If the count returns a value that is not 0 then the table is not empty .

Comment: You should post your update as an answer so people can easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `query.count()` to determine if the table is empty is not an optimal solution. While this is perfectly fine when actually run against an empty table, using `query.count()` will almost always result in a sub-optimal query when there's more than one object in the table. The reason for this is quite clear: you only care about the first object matched by this query, yet a `query.count()` will scan the whole table in order to return the total of objects that match your query.

Therefore, the ideal solution is to simply use `query.getFirst()` and check if you get any results. You should be able to handle the case where `ob` is not a `ParseObject`, e.g. the collection is either empty or no objects match your query.

Comment: You are right , I tried to use the getFirst() before I wrote my question , the thing is that when reaching this line the app crashes :) . So I assumed that the function does not work with empty tables .

Comment: getFirst() does work with empty tables -- it just won't return anything, the result will be null/undefined. So your code needs to be able to handle this case. It sounds like you depended on getFirst() *always* returning a Parse.Object, and your app crashes when that is not the case.